# Reflection off curved surface - HLSL

Tags: shader, hlsl, directx-9

Let's say I have a flat, perfect mirror.  How do I find what it's reflecting?  Easy, move the camera to a position which looks back up at the angle of incidence.

Now what if that flat mirror was curved or spherical?  How would I find the reflection of Object A if Object B was a non-flat, perfect mirror.

Presumably this would need some kind of ray-tracing (not sure how to do in HLSL ... yet), but I'm guessing this will be a performance killer.  So has anyone done this before and know what to do now? If so, is there an easier way?  How did you do it?

EDIT: This has to work in DX9

Comment: Thinking out loud - can you render a planar reflection to texture and then map that texture over whatever shape your mirror is?

Comment: There is a technique called "screen space reflections", which do some ray-tracing, but simplified to be used at realtime. Maybe it's interesting for you :)

Comment: @Gnietschow this has to work in DX9 and from a quick google search your technique seems to be specific to DX11 (please correct me if I'm wrong).  Interesting answer though, I'll keep screen space reflections in mind.

Comment: The technique came out after DX11 was released, so the examples are mostly DX11. I've implemented some kind of ssr in DX9, but never spent the time to solve all artifacts. With DX9 you can also build a deferred renderer and gain this way all needed data for the ssr-shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could at first render an environment map and then use an environment mapping shader to project it onto your curved surface. This is called Dynamic Environment Mapping or in the case of this tutorial: [Dynamic Cube Mapping](http://thangnguyendemo.blogspot.de/2009/05/dynamic-cube-mapping-for-real.html). This will result in something like this: [Dynamic Cube Mapping UDK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMxwJsGlOsA)

Comment: Sounds expensive, but I suppose that would be the way to do it with DX9.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yep, it's quite expensive since you have to render your scene multiple times. But if your want real reflections (not fake ones, like environment maps or skyboxes) it's afaik the best way to do it.